# What is the purpose of the SvgElement.tag(String tag) constructor?

Tags: svg, dart

There is no documentation in the [API doc](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_svg/SvgElement.html) for the constructors. I would like to understand the purpose/use cases for SvgElement.tag() .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SvgElement.tag(String tag)` constructor creates a new `SvgElement` for a corresponding `tag` value.

For example:

```dart
var foo = new SvgElement.tag('view');
print(foo is ViewElement); // prints 'true'
```

would create a new SvgElement specified by the `<view>` tag.

This means that the above code is the same as:

```dart
var bar = new ViewElement();
print(bar is ViewElement); // prints 'true'
```

See also the [`tag` constructor from the superclass `Element`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Element.html#Element.tag).

---

Use cases for this constructor are places where you get the value of the tag from text and want to generate a new element of that tag value.

You might get the tag from parsing the DOM, or maybe from a different API. The `tag` constructor is a way to write DOM code in a "*Darty*" way (with objects and classes) while being able to work with DOM elements via text.

In many cases, it is preferable to create this Element object instead of say, using `innerHtml` to set the DOM inside of another Element.

Compare:

```dart
var someTagName = 'view';
var someDomNode = query('#id');

// BAD
someDomNode.innerHtml = '<$someTagName> ... </$someTagName>';

// GOOD
var myElement = new SvgElement.tag(someTagName);
someDomNode.append(myElement);
```

Comment: Ok, the use case is clear for when you dynamically want to create elements for a given tag/type. I still don't understand why would you use it for a typed element like SvgElement. If you tell me it has no real purpose but is available because of the inheritance from Element I got it all clear :)

Comment: @JoãoPinto I think it is there because of inheritance and consistency. All clear. :]